# Working out the percentage of outcomes in a column within a table

Tags: sql

I am using SQL developer and have a table called table1 which looks like this (but with loads more data):

```
item_id    seller_id    warranty   postage_class
-------    ---------    --------   -------------
14         2            1          2
17         6            1          1
14         2            1          1
14         2            1          2
14         2            1          1
14         2            1          2
```

I want to identify the percentage of items sent by first class.

If anyone could help me out that would be amazing!

Comment: provide some sample data and expect result

Comment: What is the name of your table? What SQL server (MySQL, SQL Server, etc) are you sending your request to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation.  The simplest method is probably:

```
select avg(case when postage_class = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end)
from t;
```

Note this calculates a ratio between 0 and 1.  If you want a "percentage" between 0 and 100, then use 100.0 instead of 1.0.

Some databases make it possible to shorten this even further.  For instance, in Postgres, you can do:

```
select avg( (postage_class = 1)::int ) 
from t;
```